# KDE Plasma corrupted GNOME

Tags: gnome, kde, themes

I have installed KDE Plasma on my computer a few days ago, but I didn't like it, so I went back to GNOME and removed everything KDE-related. I noticed that some things are still white (I use a dark GNOME theme), so I restarted my computer. Most of the things are fine, but there are still some buttons and text that are white. Images: [image: Can't see text]
[image: Can only see if I click on it]
[image: Calculator app broken as well]

I use Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You haven't told us your OS/release details, nor what packages you installed (to get the other desktop), and then removed (was it different, what command or packages were removed/purged). Have you look to see if your settings are the same in `gnome-tweaks` ?

Comment: I tried changing my theme multiple times in `gnome-tweaks`, but that doesn't work. I installed it with `kde-plasma-desktop` and when I wanted to remove it, I did `sudo apt remove kde-plasma-desktop`, but there were other things (kdewalletmanager5, kde-settings, kdeconnect) so I removed them manually.

Comment: Have you removed the **oxygen-theme** and **breeze-theme** packages?

Comment: Unable to locate both packages... But I can still apply them in `gnome-tweaks`

Comment: Did you resolve this or do you still need help?